# Updating fields in different models through a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a products model, with a categories column. Users were able to save multiple comma separated values in the same field.

I just finished refactoring my DB so by creating a categories table, and a categories_products join.

How can I updated my categories model with the categories while also updating the join table with the corresponding category_id and product_id.

This is what I have in a rake task so far, which basically just separated the categories from the products table.

```
Product.find(:all).each do |k|
  k.categories.split(",").each do |w|
    puts k.id + " " + w
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good start.  Assuming you are using a HABTM association and that there is no collision on the word `category` (ie. your new table is something like Cats):

```
Product.find(:all).each do |product|
  product.categories.split(",").each do |category|
    if Cats.exists?(name: category)
      product.cats.create(name: category)
    else
      product.cats << Cats.find_by_name(category)
    end
  end
end
```

Also, because this is a one-time operation, rather than a task that will be executed many time, this is probably a better candidate for a DB migration.  That means it needs to inside an `up/down` or `change` grouping, and be have an inverse function written.

Comment: Based on you response, I ended up doing it like this:              `def self.add_kcsid
    Product.find(:all).each do |k|
      k.category_names.split(",").each do |w|
      k.tags.create(:cat_name => w.strip.to_s)
      end
    end
  end`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Product.find(:all).each do |k|
  k.categories.split(",").each do |w|
    Category.create(:description => w, :product_id => k.id)
  end
end
```